# SwiftUI onChange() event doesn't work on TabView when swiping

Tags: swiftui, swiftui-tabview

I would like to change the value of a text when the active tab of a TabView changes. I tried using `onChange(of: activeTab, perform: {})` to change the value of the state variable that stores the text but it seems that the closure given to `onChange()` is never called.

```swift
TabView(selection: $activeTab) {
  ForEach(exampleData) {dayMenu in
    DayMenuView(dayMenu: dayMenu)
      .padding([.leading, .bottom, .trailing])
  }
}
.onChange(of: activeTab, perform: { index in
  print(activeTab)
  withAnimation {
    activeDate = dates[1]
  }
})
```

Text view

```swift
Text(activeDate)
```

State variables

```swift
let dates = ["Montag", "Dienstag"]
    
@State private var activeTab: Int = 0
@State private var activeDate = "Montag"
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Provided code is not testable but I think it is because `activeTab` is not changed because tab views are not identified, due to tag, so try

```
TabView(selection: $activeTab) {
  ForEach(exampleData.indices, id: \.self) { index in
    DayMenuView(dayMenu: exampleData[index])
      .padding([.leading, .bottom, .trailing])
      .tag(index)
  }
}
.onChange(of: activeTab, perform: { index in
```

Comment: This and the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59157595/how-to-animate-transition-text-value-change-in-swiftui) solved my problem, thanks