# How to animate a change in the value of "Text()" in swiftUI when using conditionals?

Tags: swift, user-interface, animation, text, swiftui

I'am displaying a text whose value is changed based on a different value, this is how I implemented it:

```
Text((skateGame.getState() == .player1Set || skateGame.getState() == .player1Try) ?
                   skateGame.getPlayer1().getName() : skateGame.getPlayer2().getName())
    .font(.system(size: width * 0.08, weight: .bold, design: .rounded))
    .foregroundColor(Color.white)
    .padding(.top, height * 0.02)
    .padding(.bottom, height * 0.02)
```

How can I animate the transition between the values? For example with a bouncing motion or a fade in and out?

Comment: Would you show code of `skateGame` type? The problem might be in observing/updating view.

Comment: The text is updated without a problem, but it just flicks from one value to the next without any nice transition.

Comment: Does this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59157595/how-to-animate-transition-text-value-change-in-swiftui) help?

Comment: No sorry tried this before.